# Josephson junction: why do we need a capacitance in parallel to the inductance in the description?

Tags: electric-circuits, superconductivity, josephson-junction

To start: I am really a huge beginner in Josephson junction. I need to understand the electrical equations associated to it, I don't need to go in the superconducting physics and I would like to stick on this if possible on the answers.

My question is the following:

The current, voltage relationship for a Josephson junction are:

$$I=I_c \sin(\delta)$$
$$V=\frac{\hbar}{2e} \frac{d \delta}{d t} $$

From this, we deduce the inductance associated to the junction:

$$V  * \frac{1}{\frac{dI}{dt}} = L = \frac{\hbar}{2 e I_c \cos(\delta)}  $$

When we represent electrically a josephson junction, we say that it is an inductance in parallel to a capacitance.

**My question:**

Here, as the current is the **total one** (thus going through the inductance and the capacitance in the electrical circuit). For me it means that we can model the josephson junction with a **unique inductance** (no capacitance) that has the value calculated here.

Then, why do we say that it is modelled with a capacitance **in parallel** to an inductance ? It is in contradiction from the equations above for me. Indeed in those equations everything behave **as if** it was an inductance that depends on $\delta$ only.

I insist on the fact that I am looking on an explanation based on the electrical equations. I have no problem to consider that for some reason physically we expect to have a capacitance somewhere, but from the electrical equations such behavior is not showing up from my understanding.

Comment: 1) Since a JJ consists of an insulator between two conductors, a JJ is more a capacitor rather than inductor. 2) In relation $I = I_c \sin(\delta)$, $I$ is not the total current, but the supercurrent $I_s$. The total current is a sum of $I_s$, the capacitance current and the resistor current, therefore JJ is modeled as these three elements in parallel.

Comment: I would like to add to the above that a JJ does not have to be an insulator between two conductors, there is a whole zoo of different JJs. It could for example be two conductors separated by a fairly long segment of semiconductor. In this case the capacitance can be much smaller. So it is not generally true that the JJ is more a capacitor than an inductor.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, the small-signal model derived from the two Josephson relations is a perfect inductor.

Any parallel capacitance in the model is *not* derived from the Josephson relations at all, but only used to approximate AC impedance measurements of actual physical Josephson junctions. Since I am not after the bounty, here is Wikipedia as a relatively poor citation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect#The_RSJ_model